# Unable to change the directory using Git CMD

Tags: cmd

I'm trying: `cd /e/project/`

it says: **The system cannot find the path specified.**

But the drive and folder exists! & the same error shows to all the directory I tried to use.

note: *It works with GitBash*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/e/project` is something MSYS emulates to be able to access the different drive letters on a Windows system. Windows itself does not have a single root directory, but multiple drive letters. This is a mismatch between Linux filesystems, which only have a single root directory (`/`) and Windows filesystems, which can have multiple roots, designated by their drive letter (`A:`, `C:`, `D:`, …).

In cmd.exe or powersell, it works differently – first you have to select the drive, then change into the directory:

```
C:\> E:
E:\> cd project
E:\project\>
```

I'm not aware of a single command to switch drive and directory at the same time. Even if you did:

```
C:\> cd E:\project
```

you need to switch the drive aftewards:

```
C:\> E:
E:\project\>
```

Comment: your suggestion works, but I was able to change both drive & directory using a single command, no idea what went wrong, anyway your answer helped me, thanks sir!

Comment: The command to change folder and drive at the same time is `cd /D e:\project`